# UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification remaining time for execution

Tags: ios, swift

In my app using iOS 9.2, Swift 2.1 I need to save some data into core data when the app goes to background. For this I registered each of the view controllers in the call path for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification, with an instance method each for saving respective data.

I read on multiple places that by default the app gets about 5 seconds to finish off the execution and hence we need to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to extend it to about 5 minutes. Following is an example of the selector method that responds to the above notification.

```
func applicationEntersBackground()
{
    print("Before Extension: \(UIApplication.sharedApplication().backgroundTimeRemaining)")

    let taskID = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(nil)

    print("During Extension: \(UIApplication.sharedApplication().backgroundTimeRemaining)")

    saveCoreData()

    if(taskID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(taskID)
    }

    print("After Extension: \(UIApplication.sharedApplication().backgroundTimeRemaining)")
}
```

Following is the results of print() statements

```
Before Extension: 179.933103708318
During Extension: 179.930266333336
After Extension: 179.922843541659
```

My doubts are

1. Why is the remaining time about 180 seconds even before I requested for time extension? I tried multiple times. It is always close to 180 seconds and not the 5 seconds as suggested.
2. Why doesn't the call to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` have any impact on the remaining time?
3. Once the `applicationEntersBackground` method of a VC returns, similar notification is sent to another VC's corresponding method. Suppose 180 seconds is the total extended duration and VC1 spends about 10 seconds on notification handling, does VC2 notification handler get around 170 seconds between its `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler - endBackgroundTask` calls?
4. Between successive invocations of the notification handlers of different VCs, there is obviously a very short period where the extension request is not active. How does the timing play out in this case? Does the 5 second counter (provided it is true) come back to life as soon as an `endBackgroundTask` call is made, and possibly terminate the application before the next VC can get its notification?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/backgroundTimeRemaining) for `backgroundTimeRemaining`:

> While the app is running in the foreground, the value in this property remains suitably large. If the app starts one or more long-running tasks using the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method and then transitions to the background, the value of this property is adjusted to reflect the amount of time the app has left to run.

To answer your questions:

1. `backgroundTimeRemaining` stays around 180 while the application is in foreground so you can tell what time you'd have once you start a background task. This value is not an indicator of how long are you allowed to run without a background task.
2. `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` has an impact, as you can see, the remaining time decreased (by a small value as the method doesn't take much time)
3. What matters here is the time passed between the call to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and the one to `endBackgroundTask`. You can split whatever you need the time interval between your calls, providing you don't exceed the 180s limit
4. Once you call `endBackgroundTask` the application will be suspended, regardless it took 2 seconds or 179 seconds.

You can find out more details about application entering background [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:). I'd recommend going through the documentation, it might clarify other questions you might have on this matter.

Comment: (1) The notification is named `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` which I believe indicates that the app is already in the background. Moreover, printing the remaining time during foreground execution gave me the value of 1.79769313486232e+308. (2) My doubt is regarding the intended purpose of the call, ie to delay the suspension and increase remaining time. I think it was confused with the execution time of the call itself.

Comment: (4) Again the doubt is about having multiple successive calls to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler and endBackgroundTask` pairs from different controllers, and what rule applies during the interval between the `endBackgroundTask` call from VC1 and the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` call from VC2.